# How do I get GMT in this format +0100?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the GMT in this format of +0100, but what I'm getting is only +100.  Here's what I did so far.

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
string tz2 = String.Format
("{0}{1}{2:00}", (localZone.BaseUtcOffset >= TimeSpan.Zero) ? "" : "-", 
Math.Abs(localZone.BaseUtcOffset.Hours),
Math.Abs(localZone.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes));
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can figure out to use `:00` to get a leading zero for the minutes, but you cannot figure out to use `:00` to get a leading zero for the hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your string format to:

```
"{0}{1:00}{2:00}"
```